# How do I add 1 to the count property of whichever instance the function "increase" is invoked by?

Tags: swift

How do I add 1 to the count property of whichever instance the function "increase" is invoked by?

```
func increase() {
    ????.count += 1
}
```

Comment: Is this `increase` method a method of the same class that has the `count` property?

Answer (score 0):

If `increase()` is a method on the object with count, use `self`

```
self.count += 1
```

Or if you want it to work as a free function, you need to pass in an object

```
func increase<T: Countable>(obj: T) {
    countable.setCount(count: countable.getCount() + 1)
}
```

where Countable is:

```
protocol Countable {
    func getCount() -> Int
    func setCount(count: Int)
}
```

And a sample implementation is

```
class SimpleCounter: Countable {
    var count: Int = 0

    func getCount() -> Int {
        return count
    }
    func setCount(count: Int) {
        self.count = count
    }
}
```